# How to remove the blank in front of a string?

Tags: android

There is a string “ good morning ”. I want to remove the margin in start of the string (it is possible not the space, it maybe the line feed) and retains the middle and the back of the margin.
How to do this?

Comment: Where is this string displayed? i.e. TextView? EditText?

Comment: Use regex. See the following: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `trim()` removes leading *and* trailing whitespace, to remove only leading whitespace, you'll need to implement your own ltrim method, as follows:

```
public static String ltrim(String s) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        i++;
    }
    return s.substring(i);
}

String myString = " whitespace be gone!";
String trimmedString = ltrim( myString );
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex would work well here.  When one or more whitespace characters (\\s+) appear at the beginning of the phrase (^), replace those leading whitespace characters with an empty string.

```
private static String trimLeading(String value) {
    return value != null ? value.replaceFirst("^\\s+", "") : null;
}
```

Using JUnit/hamcrest to test it out:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertThat(trimLeading("good morning "), is("good morning "));
    assertThat(trimLeading(" good morning "), is("good morning "));
    assertThat(trimLeading("  good morning "), is("good morning "));
    assertThat(trimLeading("\ngood morning "), is("good morning "));
    assertThat(trimLeading("\rgood morning "), is("good morning "));
    assertThat(trimLeading("\tgood morning "), is("good morning "));
    assertThat(trimLeading(" \t \n \r  good morning "), is("good morning "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String b=" This is for test "
for(int i=0;i<=b.length()-1;i++)  
    {  
     char temp=b.charAt(i);  
     if(temp==' ')  
     {  
      whitespaceNumber++;  
     }  
    }  
    System.out.println("Whitespace number is : "+whitespaceNumber);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posed.